# => vs -> to access/set class variables

Tags: php

Could someone explain to me the difference between using => or ->? Is there any logical difference? Thanks!

Comment: If you can add into your question the case where you thought the two symbols might be interchangeable, that might make for a unique question. I should be interested to that code in any case.

Answer (score 4):

`=>` is used when defining arrays, and also in `foreach` loops that use keys, e.g.

```
$foo = array('bar' => 'baz');
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {...}
```

`->` is used to refer to object members, e.g.

```
$obj->method();
$obj->property;
```

They are never interchangeable.

Comment: There are other uses of => as well.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert added `foreach` example. AFAIK they are the only two uses...

Comment: @AbhiBeckert What other uses?

Comment: @DamienPirsy checke the language specification, I'm aware of at least 4 of them, but there are probably more.

Comment: @Abhi, I should be interested too what the other uses are - you've got me curious!

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Nope, I'm trying but can't find the other 2 uses (besides arrays and foreach) you're talking about. Please stop being mysterious and tell us! :)